# Image Averaging and Saving output

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I'm planning to process quite a large number of images and would like to average every 5 consecutive images. My images are saved as .dm4 file format.

Essentially, I want to produce a single averaged image output for each 5 images that I can save. So for instance, if I had 400 images, I would like to get 80 averaged images that would represent the 400 images.

I'm aware that there's the Running Z Projector plugin but it does a running average and doesn't give me the reduced number of images I'm looking for. Is this something that has already been done before?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `dm4` format images, but if you can get them to any other standard format of the 200+ formats that ImageMagick supports, the command to average them is simple - `convert im1.jpg im2.jpg im3.jp im4.jpg im5.jpg -average output.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the link. Unfortunately, .dm4 stores the image header file which includes the image scale so I should probably keep them as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Image>Stacks>Tools>[Grouped Z_Projector](http://imagej.net/plugins/group.html) does exactly you want.

I found it by opening the command finder ('L') and filtering on "project".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise there was a grouped averaging function.